# Установка библиотеки для питона на удаленный сервер centos

Tags: python, linux, centos

Выполняю команду pip install xlwt, выдает ошибку.

> Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authorization RequiredUnable to establish SSL connection.

Настраивал прокси до этого, все нормально работала.

Comment: Проверьте черные и белые списки прокси. Возможно, pypi.org блокируется. Так же проверьте [настройки pip для работы с прокси](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#basic-authentication-credentials)